# Force partition pruning on Oracle

Tags: oracle, performance, optimization, partitioning, oracle12c

I have a query similar to this

```
select *
from small_table A
inner join huge_table B on A.DATE =B.DATE
```

The huge_table is partitioned by DATE, and the PK is DATE, some_id and some_other_id (so the join not is done by pk index).
small_table just contains a few dates.

The total cost of the SQL is 48 minutes

By some reason the explain plan give me a "PARTITION RANGE (ALL)" with a high numbers on cardinality. Looks like access to the full table, not just the partitions indicated by small_table.DATE

If I put the SQL inside a loop and do

```
for o in (select date from small_table)
loop
    select *
    from small_table A
    inner join huge_table B on A.DATE =B.DATE
    where B.DATE=O.DATE
end loop;
```

Only takes 2 minutes 40 seconds (the full loop).
There is any way to force the partition pruning on Oracle 12c?

Additional info:

`small_table` has 37 records for 13 different dates. `huge_table` has 8,000 million of records with 179 dates/partitions. The SQL needs one field from `small_table`, but I can tweak the SQL to not use it

Update:

With the `use_nl hint`, now the cardinality show in the execution plan is more accurate and the execution time downs from 48 minutes to 4 minutes.

```
select /* use_nl(B) */*
from small_table A
inner join huge_table B on A.DATE =B.DATE
```

Comment: small_table has variable number of registries. Is truncated and populated on each execution.

Comment: Sorry I have a problem editing my previous comment.
small_table have 37 registries for 13 different dates.huge_table has 8.000 millions of registries with 179 dates/partitions.
About the statistics. How can I get it?

Comment: Yes, the stats from user_tables are correct, 37 registries.
The SQL need one field from small_table, but I can tweak the SQL to not use it.

Comment: Sorry can't move to chat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like the problem:

> "`small_table` have 37 registries for 13 different dates. `huge_table` has 8.000 millions of registries with 179 dates/partitions....
>   The SQL need one field from `small_table`, but I can tweak the SQL to not use it "

According to the SQL you posted you're joining the two tables on just their DATE columns with no additional conditions. If that's really the case you are generating a cross join in which each partition of `huge_table` is joined to `small_table` 2-3 times. So your result set may be much large than you're expecting, which means more database effort, which means more time.

The other thing to notice is that the cardinality of  `small_table` to `huge_table` partitions is about 1:4; the optimizer doesn't know that there are really only thirteen distinct `huge_table` partitions in play.

Optimization ought to be a science and this is more guesswork than anything but try this:

```
select B.*
from ( select /*+ cardinality(t 13) */
             distinct t.date
        from small_table t ) A
inner join huge_table B 
    on A.DATE =B.DATE
```

This should communicate to the optimizer that only a small percentage of the `huge_table` partitions are required, which may make it choose partition pruning. Also it removes that Cartesian product, which should improve performance too. Obviously you will need to apply that tweak you mentioned, to remove the need to query anything else from `small_table`.

Comment: Thanks, finally a small variation do the trick.
Using /* use_nl(B)*/ force a "PARTITION RANGE (ITERATOR)".
and now the result is close to the loop.